# Finding the spectrum of this operator

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and let $\psi_1,\psi_2$ be linearly independent vectors and let $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ be linearly independent  vectors in $X$. Define the operator $T$ in $B(X)$ by$$Tx=\langle x;{\varphi_1}\rangle\psi_1+\langle x;{\varphi_2}\rangle\psi_2,\quad x\in X.$$ Determine the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ and calculate $(T-\lambda)^{-1}, \lambda\notin\sigma(T).$

I started with: $\sigma(T)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb C\mid T-\lambda I \text{ is not invertible}\}$. So I tried to find values of $\lambda$ for which $T-\lambda I$ is invertible and my answer would be $\mathbb C$ without those values. But to make shure you've got exactly all of them you need an *iff* statement on when an operator is invertible and I can't think of anything else but the definition. This is an increadably cumbersome procedure and I doubt that it is what I'm supposed to do here.

I would like some help with finding the spectrum. I don't really know where to start.

N.B. I prefer a good hint over a complete answer.

Comment: Have you got any updates on this? Did your professor have a clever trick to solve this?

Comment: @ChrisCave I've submitted my homework via email. I've been bugging him for the correct answers, but he's not responded yet. I'll update (perhaps as an answer) when he does.

Answer (score 3):

For a hint to determine the spectrum. It's obvious that $T$ is a compact operator so for any $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ either $\lambda \neq 0$ and is an eigenvalue or $\lambda = 0$ and is a limit point of $\sigma(T)$. In fact $0$ is an eigenvector, just take a vector that is orthogonal to both $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$.

Clearly, $\mbox{Im}(T) = \mbox{span}(\psi_1, \psi_2)$ so it is enough to find a solution of this form:
\begin{equation*}
T(\alpha \psi_1 + \beta\psi_2) = \lambda(\alpha \psi_1 + \beta\psi_2)
\end{equation*}
for some $\alpha,\beta ,\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. By definition we have that
\begin{equation*}
T(\alpha \psi_1 + \beta\psi_2) = \left[ \langle \psi_1, \varphi_1 \rangle + \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \langle \psi_2, \varphi_1 \rangle\right] \alpha \psi_1 + \left[ \langle \psi_2, \varphi_2 \rangle + \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \langle \psi_1, \varphi_2 \rangle\right] \beta \psi_2
\end{equation*}

These two coefficients in the square brackets need to be the same.

EDIT:
So this is the best to my knowledge how to get the spectrum. There could be a clever trick to this but at the moment I can't see it. It could be using an application of Riesz Representation theorem but I'm unsure.

Equating the coefficients we get:
\begin{equation*}
\beta^2 +\left( \frac{\langle \psi_1, \varphi_1 \rangle - \langle \psi_2, \varphi_2 \rangle}{\langle \psi_2, \varphi_1 \rangle} \right) \alpha \beta - \frac{\langle \psi_1, \varphi_2 \rangle}{\langle \psi_2 , \varphi_1 \rangle}\alpha^2 = 0
 \end{equation*}

By quadratic solution we have that
\begin{equation*}
\beta = - \alpha \left( \frac{\langle \psi_1, \varphi_1 \rangle - \langle \psi_2, \varphi_2 \rangle}{\langle \psi_2, \varphi_1 \rangle} \right) \pm \frac{\alpha}{\langle \psi_2, \varphi_1 \rangle} \sqrt{(\langle \psi_1, \varphi_1 \rangle - \langle \psi_2, \varphi_2 \rangle)^2 + \langle \psi_1, \varphi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_2, \varphi_1 \rangle}
\end{equation*}

This is where you get the two eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance, but I'm not quite seeing the answer just yet. That is: I understand that I should solve two equations with $\lambda=[*]=[**]$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. But this is a really cumbersome and time consuming system of equations (wich is not likely what I'm supposed to do, knowing my proffesor...). Am I perhaps missing some things that obviously cancel out?

Comment: You don't need to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you only need to find a suitable choice for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: But it seems to me that would only give you one value for $\lambda$. How can you know there aren't any more. Could you maybe elaborate you answer a bit?

Comment: Your operator has rank $2$, and so has at most $2$ non-zero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

What follows isn't pretty and doesn't give a real answer, but, I think, tells you what's going on. If nothing else, take it as an oversized comment.

So, $T$ is a general rank $2$ operator on $H$; by construction, $\operatorname{im}(T) = \operatorname{span}\{\psi_1,\psi_2\}$, whilst $\ker(T)^\perp = \operatorname{span}\{\phi_1,\phi_2\}$. Thus, if you set $H_0 := \operatorname{span}\{\phi_1,\phi_2,\psi_1,\psi_2\}$, then, with respect to the orthogonal decomposition $H = H_0 \oplus H_0^\perp$, $T = T_0 \oplus 0_{H_0^\perp}$, where $T_0 := T|_{H_0} : H_0 \to H_0$ is a linear operator on a *finite*-dimensional vector space. In particular, then,
$$
 T - \lambda I_H = (T_0 - \lambda I_{H_0}) \oplus -\lambda I_{H_0^\perp},
$$
from which we see that $T - \lambda I_H$ is invertible if and only if $\lambda \neq 0$ and $T_0 - \lambda I_{H_0}$ is invertible on $H_0$. Hence:

1. The non-zero eigenvalues of $T$ on $H$ are precisely the non-zero eigenvalues of $T_0 - \lambda I_{H_0}$ on $H_0$.
2. If $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$, then $(T-\lambda I_H)^{-1} = (T_0 - \lambda I_{H_0})^{-1} \oplus -\lambda^{-1}I_{H_0^\perp}$.

So, at the end of the day, *everything* reduces to studying the operator $T_0$ on the finite-dimensional vector space $H_0$, and hence, upon choosing your favourite basis for $H_0$ (e.g., the outcome of Gram–Schmidt applied to $\{\phi_1,\phi_2,\psi_1,\psi_2\}$), to studying what's at most a $4 \times 4$ matrix.